# To relate one record to another in MongoDB, is it ok to use a slug?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say we have two models like this:

```
User:
   _ _id
   - name
   - email

Company:
   - _id
   _ name
   _ slug
```

Now let's say I need to connect a user to the company. A user can have one company assigned. To do this, I can add a new field called `companyID` in the user model. But I'm not sending the `_id` field to the front end. All the requests that come to the API will have the `slug` only. There are two ways I can do this:

1) Add `slug` to relate the company: If I do this, I can take the slug sent from a request and directly query for the company.

2) Add the `_id` of the company: If I do this, I need to first use the slug to query for the company and then use the `_id` returned to query for the required data.

May I please know which way is the best? Is there any extra benefit when using the `_id` of a record for the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with the 2nd approach. There are several issues to consider when deciding on which field to use as a join key (this is true of all DBs, not just Mongo):

1. The field must be unique. I'm not sure exactly what the 'slug' field in your schema represents, but if there is any chance this could be duplicated, then don't use it.
2. The field must not change. Strictly speaking, you *can* change a key field but the only way to safely do so is to simultaneously change it in all the child tables atomically. This is a difficult thing to do reliably because a) you have to know which tables are using the field (maybe some other developer added another table that you're not aware of) b) If you do it one at a time, you'll introduce race conditions c) If any of the updates fail, you'll have inconsistent data and corrupted parent-child links. Some SQL DBs have a cascading-update feature to solve this problem, but Mongo does not. It's a hard enough problem that you really, really don't want to change a key field if you don't have to.
3. The field must be indexed. Strictly speaking this isn't true, but if you're going to join on it, then you will be running a lot of queries on it, so you'll need to index it.

For these reasons, it's almost always recommended to use a key field that serves *solely* as a key field, with no actual information stored in it. Plenty of people have been burned using things like Social Security Numbers, drivers licenses, etc. as key fields, either because there can be duplicates (e.g. SSNs can be duplicated if people are using fake numbers, or if they don't have one), or the numbers can change (e.g. drivers licenses).

Plus, by doing so, you can format the key field to optimize for speed of unique generation and indexing. For example, if you use SSNs, you need to check the SSN against the rest of the DB to ensure it's unique. That takes time if you have millions of records. Similarly for slugs, which are text fields that need to be hashed and checked against an index. OTOH, mongoDB essentially uses UUIDs as keys, which means it doesn't have to check for uniqueness (the algorithm guarantees a high statistical likelihood of uniqueness).

The bottomline is that there are very good reasons not to use a "real" field as your key if you can help it. Fortunately for you, mongoDB already gives you a great key field which satisfies all the above criteria, the _id field. Therefore, you should use it. Even if slug is not a "real" field and you generate it the exact same way as an _id field, why bother? Why does a record have to have 2 unique identifiers?

The second issue in your situation is that you don't expose the company's _id field to the user. Intuitively, it seems like that should be a valuable piece of information that shouldn't be given out willy-nilly. But the truth is, it has no informational value by itself, because, as stated above, a key *should have no actual information*. The place to implement security is in the query, ensuring that the user doing the query has permission to access the record / specific fields that she's asking for. Hiding the key is a classic security-by-obscurity that doesn't actually improve security.

The only time to hide your primary key is if you're using a poorly thought-out key that *does* contain useful information. For example, an invoice Id that increments by 1 for each invoice can be used by someone to figure out how many orders you get in a day. Auto-increment Ids can also be easily guessed (if my invoice is #5, can I snoop on invoice #6?). Fortunately, Mongo uses UUIDs so there's really no information leaking out (except maybe for timing attacks on its cryptographic algorithm? And if you're worried about that, you need far more in-depth security considerations than this post :-).

Look at it another way: if a slug reliably points to a specific company and user, then how is it more secure than just using the _id?

That said, there are *some* instances where exposing a secondary key (like slugs) is helpful, none of which have to do with security. For example, if in the future you need to migrate DB platforms and need to re-generate keys because the new platform can't use your old ones; or if users will be manually typing in identifiers, then it's helpful to give them something easier to remember like slugs. But even in those situations, you can use the slug as a handy identifier for users to use, but in your DB, you should still use the company ID to do the actual join (like in your option #2). Check out this discussion about the pros/cons of exposing _ids to users:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218306/why-not-expose-a-primary-key

So my recommendation would be to go ahead and give the user the company Id (along with the slug if you want a human-readable format e.g. for URLs, although mongo _ids can be used in a URL). They can send it back to you to get the user, and you can (after appropriate permission checks) do the join and send back the user data. If you don't want to expose the company Id, then I'd recommend your option #2, which is essentially the same thing except you're adding an additional query to first get the company Id. IMHO, that's a waste of cycles for no real improvement in security, but if there are other considerations, then it's still acceptable. And both of those options are better than using the slug as a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

Second way of approach is the best,That is Add the _id of the company.

Using _id is the best way of practise to query any kind of information,even complex queries can be solved using _id as it is a unique ObjectId created by Mongodb. Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). We may populate a single document, multiple documents, plain object, multiple plain objects, or all objects returned from a query.